# Value or Numeric error in a function and I can't detect where I have gone wrong Oracle

Tags: oracle, exception, plsql, oracle11g, stored-functions

I have a function written in SQL developer and every time I want to execute I get value or numeric error and I simply cannot get where I have gone wrong.

This is my code so if someone can give me some tips on where my mistake is hidden I would be grateful.

The types that are used in the code are defined and mostly consist of varchar objects and tables of objects and I am properly putting them as an input variable.

I am getting frustrated with that error because I have written similar function already and it was working just fine, but now I have spent 4 hours on trying to figure out where value or numeric error is.

```
function get_tbank_service_status_bulk (
        p_bank_id_tab IN bank_id_tab,
        p_service_status_tab OUT bank_service_status_tab
      ) return ITF_RETURN_REC
    is
    v_count         number;
    n_message_id    number;
    k_out           number := 0;
    ret_rec         ITF_RETURN_REC;

    cursor tbstatus_cur (p_bank_id_tab bank_id_tab)
     is select tbc.rowid row_id, tbc.BANK_ID bank_id, tbc.service_status service_status
    from TABLE (CAST (p_bank_id_tab AS bank_id_tab)) bid, mdm.mdm_tbank_customer tbc where bid.bank_id=tbc.bank_id ;

    type cur_tbstatus_tab is table of tbstatus_cur%rowtype;
    l_tbstatus_status           cur_tbstatus_tab;
   BEGIN
      select MESSAGE_ID_SEQ.nextval into n_message_id from dual;
      v_count := p_bank_id_tab.COUNT;
      p_service_status_tab  := bank_service_status_tab();
      if v_count = 0 then
         return itf_return_rec(0, ' ', n_message_id, ' ');
      end if;
        open tbstatus_cur(p_bank_id_tab);
           fetch tbstatus_cur bulk collect into l_tbstatus_status;
              for i in l_tbstatus_status.first..l_tbstatus_status.last
                loop
                    if  l_tbstatus_status(i).row_id is null then
                        p_service_status_tab.extend;
                        k_out := p_service_status_tab.last;
                        p_service_status_tab(k_out) := bank_service_status_rec(l_tbstatus_status(i).bank_id, -1);
                         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(  'nes1 || : ' );
                    else
                    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(  'nes4 || : ' );
                        p_service_status_tab.extend;
                        k_out := p_service_status_tab.last;
                        p_service_status_tab(k_out) := bank_service_status_rec(l_tbstatus_status(i).bank_id,l_tbstatus_status(i).service_status);
                    end if;
                end loop; 
    if tbstatus_cur%isopen then
        close tbstatus_cur;
    end if;
    ret_rec := ITF_RETURN_REC(0, ' ', n_message_id, ' ');
    commit; 
    return ret_rec;
    exception
    when others then
      rollback;
      if tbstatus_cur%isopen then
        close tbstatus_cur;
      end if;
      ret_rec := ITF_RETURN_REC(-1, 'Error while performing operation!', n_message_id, SQLERRM);
      mdm_itf_logger.log_end('ERROR');
      return ret_rec;

    end get_tbank_service_status_bulk;
```

Comment: What is the line where the error occurs?

Comment: first of all add `create or replace ` to the beginning.

Comment: Please include the full error stack you get, and also the statement that calls the function when it gets that exception - the issue may be in the caller (trying to use or assign the return value) rather than in the function. The type definitions might be relevant too.

Comment: In addition to the info the others have asked for the error could be coming from the functions called by your code, `bank_service_status_rec` or `itf_return_rec`. But definitely start with the line where the error occurs and the full error stack. That is Oracle literally telling you which line of code causes the error.

Comment: Although if you're looking the output from `ret_rec := ITF_RETURN_REC(-1, 'Error while performing operation!', n_message_id, SQLERRM);` that may not be so helpful. It's a better idea to log  the whole stack with [`DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_STACK` function](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_util.htm#ARPLS73242).

Comment: The simplest debugging step would be to comment out the exception handler, as then the raw error stack should show the line number.

Comment: By the way, formatting your code is a good way to get in control of it.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to list out where exactly the error is happening.

```
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line( SQLERRM || UTL_TCP.crlf || DBMS_UTILITY.format_error_backtrace );
```