# Inserting values into table of records type

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am creating a procedure and I want to store multiple values into table of records type and I am trying to insert values by cursor but I get this errors :

> Error(14,7): PL/SQL: Statement ignored
>
> Error(14,12): PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to
>   '+'
>
> Error(15,7): PL/SQL: Statement ignored
>
> Error(15,12): PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type

The lines that are mentioned in errors are these two :

```
n := n+1;
          ulaz(n) := bank_id_rec(tmp_row.bank_id);

create or replace PROCEDURE BULK_STATUS_JOB
    IS
      CURSOR tmp_cursor
      IS
        SELECT bank_id FROM mdm_tbank_customer;
      n INTEGER :=0;
      ulaz bank_id_tab;
      izlaz bank_service_status_tab;
      rec itf_return_rec;
    BEGIN
      OPEN tmp_cursor;
      LOOP
        FOR n in tmp_cursor LOOP
          n := n+1;
          ulaz(n) := bank_id_rec(tmp_row.bank_id);
       END LOOP;
        EXIT
      WHEN tmp_cursor%notfound;
      END LOOP;  
        rec := mdm_tbank_itf_sb.get_tbank_service_status_bulk(ulaz, izlaz);
        FOR i IN izlaz.first..izlaz.last
        LOOP
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(ulaz(i).bank_id);
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(izlaz(i).bank_id || ': '||izlaz(i).service_status);
        END LOOP;
    EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      dbms_output.put_line(SQLERRM);
      IF tmp_cursor%ISOPEN THEN
        CLOSE tmp_cursor;
      END IF;
    END BULK_STATUS_JOB;
```

Comment: Does this mean you've resolved the ORA-01722 [in your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57951542/146325)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an issue in

```
FOR n in tmp_cursor LOOP
          n := n+1;
```

You have used the same name for loop identifier and local variable but when it is used in the scope of the loop, n represents tmp_cursor. so 
`n := n+1` represents `tmp_cursor := tmp_cursor + 1;` which is invalid.

So please change the identifier to some other name (let's say nn) and use it all over the loop as follows.

```
FOR nn in tmp_cursor LOOP -- nn represents loop identifier
              n := n+1; -- n represents your local variable declared by you
```

Also, there are few other issues which seem unnecessary, see the comments in the following final code

```
create or replace PROCEDURE BULK_STATUS_JOB
    IS
      CURSOR tmp_cursor
      IS
        SELECT bank_id FROM mdm_tbank_customer;
      n INTEGER :=0;
      ulaz bank_id_tab;
      izlaz bank_service_status_tab;
      rec itf_return_rec;
    BEGIN
      --OPEN tmp_cursor; -- not needed
      --LOOP -- not needed
        FOR nn in tmp_cursor LOOP -- changed loop variable name to nn
          n := n+1;
          ulaz(n) := bank_id_rec(nn.bank_id); --- used nn.bank_id
       END LOOP;
        --EXIT -- not needed
      --WHEN tmp_cursor%notfound; -- not needed
      --END LOOP;  -- not needed
        rec := mdm_tbank_itf_sb.get_tbank_service_status_bulk(ulaz, izlaz);
        FOR i IN izlaz.first..izlaz.last
        LOOP
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(ulaz(i).bank_id);
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(izlaz(i).bank_id || ': '||izlaz(i).service_status);
        END LOOP;
    EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      dbms_output.put_line(SQLERRM);
      IF tmp_cursor%ISOPEN THEN
        CLOSE tmp_cursor;
      END IF;
    END BULK_STATUS_JOB;
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Using `SELECT bank_id_rec(bank_id) BULK COLLECT INTO ulaz FROM ..` should be quicker.

Comment: And if this code is going anywhere near production, you should not simply display the error message in the exception handler. You should write the error out to a log table and/or propagate it out unhandled so that the failure is obvious. Don't already have an error logging utility? Check out Logger: https://github.com/OraOpenSource/Logger